# C# Excel.Interop Numberformat

Tags: c#, number-formatting, excel-interop

i've got the following problem:
I try to apply a numberformat to a specific cell so I get 2 decimals. Additional every 0, empty cell or null value should be replaced by "-".
E.g.:

```
23,4  --> 23,40
56    --> 56,00
empty --> -
0     --> -
null  --> -
```

How can I realize this?

Comment: Okay, so what was your question?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
range.NumericFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)";
```

Comment: do you mean range.numberformat... i can't find any numericformat

Comment: are you really using `excel-interop`? because that's how it is named : [Range.NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.numberformat(v=office.14).aspx)